# Retorno status 302 no submit do formulário

Tags: laravel-5.6

fiz a migração do meu projeto laravel 5.4 pro 5.6, porém em um form novo estou tendo o retorno 302 ao dar o submit no form, é um form normal como os diversos outros no meu sistema, porém este em específico está com este retorno...

[image: 302]

Deve ser algo que estou deixando passar, porém não estou encontrando... talvez seja por hoje ser segunda feira rs...

Abaixo os códigos:

> resumoplano.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('renovaPlano')}}" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h2> Selecione o plano:</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <select name="plano">
                            <option value="0"></option>
                            @foreach($planos as $plano)
                                <option value="{{$plano->id}}">{{$plano->descricao}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12" id="loader-busca" style="height: 60px;width: 100%; display: none">
                        <div class='loader-busca'>
                            <div class='loader-busca--dot'></div>
                            <div class='loader-busca--dot'></div>
                            <div class='loader-busca--dot'></div>
                            <div class='loader-busca--dot'></div>
                            <div class='loader-busca--dot'></div>
                            <div class='loader-busca--dot'></div>
                            <div class='loader-busca--text'></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 18px;">
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin:0; padding: 0">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" name="numeronotas" readonly>
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span><label style=" top:-15px !important;
                                                                        font-size:14px !important;
                                                                        color:#5264AE !important;">Doc. Fiscais/Mês</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin:0; padding: 0">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" name="usuarios" readonly>
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span><label style=" top:-15px !important;
                                                                        font-size:14px !important;
                                                                        color:#5264AE !important;">Usuários</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" name="valor" readonly>
                            <span class="highlight"></span>
                            <span class="bar"></span><label style=" top:-15px !important;
                                                                    font-size:14px !important;
                                                                    color:#5264AE !important;">Valor</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default credit-card-box">
                        <div class="panel-heading" style="min-height: 40px;">
                            <div class="col-md-7" >
                                <h3 class="panel-title display-td">Meio de pagamento</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-cc-visa"></i><i class="fa fa-2x fa-cc-mastercard"></i>
                            </div>                    
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row text-center">
                                <h4>Dados do proprietário do cartão*</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                                                                        font-size:14px !important;
                                                                        color:#5264AE !important;">Nome completo</label>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input 
                                                type="text"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="cardName"
                                                placeholder="Nome (conforme escrito no cartão)"
                                                data-toggle="tooltip" title="O campo nome deverá ser preenchido exatamente como está informado na frente de seu cartão de crédito."
                                                autocomplete="cc-name"
                                                maxlength="100" size="100"
                                                required autofocus 
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                                                                        font-size:14px !important;
                                                                        color:#5264AE !important;">cpf</label>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input 
                                                type="tel"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="cpf"
                                                placeholder="CPF"
                                                autocomplete="cpf"
                                                maxlength="100" size="100"
                                                required 
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                                                                        font-size:14px !important;
                                                                        color:#5264AE !important;">Nascimento</label>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input 
                                                type="tel"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="birthDate"
                                                placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"
                                                autocomplete="dt-nasc"
                                                data-toggle="tooltip" title="Data de nascimento no formato dia/mês/ano."
                                                maxlength="120" size="120"
                                                required
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="cardNumber" style=" top:-15px !important;
                                                                        font-size:14px !important;
                                                                        color:#5264AE !important;">Número do cartão</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input 
                                                type="tel"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="cardNumber"
                                                placeholder="Número do cartão"
                                                autocomplete="cc-number"
                                                maxlength="120" size="120"
                                                required
                                            />
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="cardExpiry" style=" top:-15px !important;
                                                                        font-size:14px !important;
                                                                        color:#5264AE !important;"><span class="hidden-xs">Expira em</span><span class="visible-xs-inline">Data</span></label>
                                            <input 
                                                type="tel" 
                                                class="form-control" 
                                                name="cardExpiry"
                                                placeholder="MM / AA"
                                                autocomplete="cc-exp"
                                                data-toggle="tooltip" title="Data de expiração do cartão, geralmente encontrado na frente do cartão, como 'Válido até:'."
                                                maxlength="10" size="10"
                                                required 
                                            />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="cardCVC" style="    top:-15px !important;
                                                                        font-size:14px !important;
                                                                        color:#5264AE !important;">CVC</label>
                                            <input 
                                                type="tel" 
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="cardCVC"
                                                placeholder="CVC"
                                                autocomplete="cc-csc"
                                                data-toggle="tooltip" title="O campo CVC pode ser encontrado na parte de trás do cartão, próximo ao local de assinatura."
                                                maxlength="4" size="4"
                                                required
                                            />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <p class="small btn-danger text-center">* estes dados não são armazenados.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="display:none;">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <p class="payment-errors"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Finalizar">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

> rota

```
Route::post('empresa/renova', 'EmpresaController@renova')->name('renovaPlano');
```

Obs: a rota não está utilizando nenhum middleware específico...

> EmpresaController.php

```
public function renova(Request $request){
    //deveria chegar aqui
    dd($request);

    //telefone
    $empresa = Empresa::where('id', Auth::user()->idempresa)->first();

    $celular = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $empresa->telefone());
    $ddd = substr($celular, 0,2);
    $numeroCel = substr($celular, 2);

    //...//

}
```

> edit

Não é apresentado nenhum erro, simplesmente ocorre o refresh da página como se o submit tivesse funcionado...